# Mysql SUM of SUM

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to make a sum of sum in one select query?

Something like this:

```
SELECT id, SUM(current_price - bought_price)*amount AS profit FROM purchase WHERE purchase_id = 1 GROUP BY id
```

I want the sum of all returned `profit`

Comment: Provide your table structure and data example.

Comment: Just remove the `Group By Id`, and the column `Id` from select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT id, SUM(current_price - bought_price)*amount AS profit
FROM purchase
WHERE purchase_id = 1
GROUP BY id ;
```

If you want the total profit, just remove the `group by` and rephrase the `sum()`:

```
SELECT SUM(current_price*amount - bought_price*amount) AS profit
FROM purchase
WHERE purchase_id = 1;
```

EDIT:

You can also write this as:

```
SELECT SUM((current_price - bought_price)*amount) AS profit
FROM purchase
WHERE purchase_id = 1;
```

By the way, the original formulation isn't correct.  You want to use the same form with the `group by`:

```
SELECT id, SUM((current_price - bought_price)*amount) AS profit
FROM purchase
WHERE purchase_id = 1
GROUP BY id;
```

The problem with your version is that `amount` is taken from on arbitrary row for each `id`.  If there is only one row in `purchase` for each `id`, then no problem.  But if there are multiple rows for an `id`, then the query in the question will produce indeterminate results.  (You are using a MySQL extension to `group by` that is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).)

Comment: Consider using `SUM(amount*(current_price-bought_price))`

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are asking:

```
SELECT tmp.id, SUM(tmp.profit)
FROM (
  SELECT id, SUM(current_price - bought_price)*amount AS profit 
  FROM purchase 
  WHERE purchase_id = 1
  GROUP BY id 
) AS tmp
```

but the result is the same as

```
SELECT SUM(current_price - bought_price)*amount AS profit 
FROM purchase 
WHERE purchase_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, SUM(current_price - bought_price)*amount 
AS profit FROM purchase WHERE purchase_id = 1 GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP;
```

You can use WITH ROLLUP modifier for GROUP BY (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html). As result you will get all summary by product and TOTAL for all product groups.